# Swiper: use of `data-srcset`/`data-src` breaks media conditions

Tags: swiper.js

When setting up Swiper for lazy loading, we have to use `data-srcset` and `data-src` instead of `srcset` and `src` on the image tag (see [Documentation](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#lazy)).

```html
<!-- Slider main container -->
<div class="swiper-container">
    <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img
            class="swiper-lazy"

            data-srcset="
                https://via.placeholder.com/400x200 400w,
                https://via.placeholder.com/800x400 800w,
                https://via.placeholder.com/1200x600 1200w,
                https://via.placeholder.com/1600x800 1600w,
                https://via.placeholder.com/2400x1200 2400w,
                "

            sizes="
                (max-width: 800px) 400px,
                (max-width: 1200px) 600px,
                (max-width: 1920px) 800px,
                1200px
            "
            data-src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200" 
      >
      <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader"></div>
      </div> 

    </div>
    <!-- If we need pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

    <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

    <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
    <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>
```

## Expected behaviour

Browser choses higher resolution images using the media conditions declared in `sizes`.

## Issue

Browser choses higher resolution not as declared but earlier.
Check out this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sjf_dev/kvjos7f8/).
In my example the media conditions are set to be `width: 800px`, `width: 1200px`, (…).
However the browser actually uses `width: 490px`, `width: 693px`, (…).

## `srcset` and `src` works, but…

I found out that using `srcset` and `src` on the image tag leads to correct use of the media conditions declared in `sizes`. However I lose the lazy loading functionality. Check out this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sjf_dev/7oysxcox/).

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?
I tested on Chrome v63 with DevTools and disabled cache.
Can you reproduce?